# Is it safe to feed bacon to a pet pig?

Tags: diet, pig

I'm simply curious, I have read that pigs make very good house pets and are delighted to eat just about anything

Firstly, would a pig eat pork?

If so, is it safe to feed a pig its own kind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Humans and swine/pigs share very similar anatomy and physiology.  Dietary requirements and restrictions are similar between pigs and people. Feeding uncooked pork products to a pig (*or a person*) can lead to cholera or [Trichinosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trichinosis), but cooked pork is fine in moderation. There are of moral considerations for the consumption pork by pigs and people ([*Deuteronomy 14:8*](http://biblehub.com/deuteronomy/14-8.htm)), but also like us they are [omnivores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omnivore) and need a significant percentage of [protein in their diet](http://www.merckmanuals.com/vet/management_and_nutrition/nutrition_pigs/nutritional_requirements_of_pigs.html) in commercial production it is not unusual to feed pork [offal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offal) to pigs that will go to market, chances are if you eat pork, you have eaten pork that has eaten pork.  In fact the [FDA has guidelines on preparing it.](http://www.fda.gov/ICECI/ComplianceManuals/CompliancePolicyGuidanceManual/ucm074717.htm)

Moral/ethical questions about having a pet pig and preparing cooked pork products for either of you, is beyond the scope of this site.  Health wise, the health/diet impacts for either of you are essentially the same.

References

- [Swine Nutrition, Second Edition, Austin J. Lewis, L. Lee Southern; CRC Press, 2014](https://books.google.com/books?id=NWSo6OdeCoAC&pg=PA7&dq=swine+and+humans&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Kb-yVIu8NMykgwSX5IPQDQ&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=swine%20and%20humans&f=false)
- [Biomaterials Science: An Introduction to Materials in Medicine, Buddy D. Ratner
  Academic Press, 2004](https://books.google.com/books?id=Uzmrq7LO7loC&pg=PA386&dq=swine+and+humans&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Kb-yVIu8NMykgwSX5IPQDQ&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=swine%20and%20humans&f=false)
- [Hog cholera, By C. G. Cole, U.S. Dept. of Agriculture, 1953](https://books.google.com/books?id=PdTEmbxE5iUC&pg=PA10&dq=Hog+feed+pork&hl=en&sa=X&ei=iL6yVM3fOYWZNuWChLAE&ved=0CD4Q6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=Hog%20feed%20pork&f=false)
- [Where’s the (Not) Meat? (USDA, PDF)](http://www.ers.usda.gov/media/147867/ldpm20901.pdf)

Comment: worth noting, pigs will eat other pigs

Answer (score 1):

I have known a few pig farmers, they have historically fed pork to their pigs. That is not just pigs that will go to market but some to show pigs as well. As to specific dietary improvements that may have over other diets for show pigs I cannot attest to.

On a personal note, I believe feeding pork to a pig is the best way to get the most "pork filled flavor in every bite of pork". It just seems like you get more pork for your buck.

Answer (score 0):

It’s about the same as humans eating human flesh. There’s nothing physically wrong with it- but why? Pigs can live just as humans can on a varied whole food plant based diet. 
You could feed a dog to a dog with the same results. Any corpse can be a considered meal.

Comment: It's not the same, as pigs are already known to eat other pigs (as many animals do to their own kind).